# why am i not able to download eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

i am trying to install eclipse for Java development.
But after hitting install i get "installation failed with an error. Show log"

This is the log file:

```
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository code=13 Retry another mirror
  ERROR: org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core code=0 Repeated attemps to download http://mirrors.xmission.com/eclipse/oomph/drops/milestone/S20191105-074631-1.15.0-M2/plugins/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.tablecombo_1.2.0.201910251134.jar from the same site
  java.io.IOException: Repeated attemps to download http://mirrors.xmission.com/eclipse/oomph/drops/milestone/S20191105-074631-1.15.0-M2/plugins/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.tablecombo_1.2.0.201910251134.jar from the same site
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.download(CachingTransport.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.download(CachingTransport.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.getArtifact(MirrorRequest.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: do you have trouble downloading or installing eclipse ??

Comment: Not sure how this mirror got selected but the file does not exist anymore: HTTP 404.

Comment: Did you see this part of the error message? "**Retry another mirror**" --- Maybe you should follow the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have downloaded a corrupted artifact that now has been cached, and the installation won't run. Try by going under the `.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/cache` path of your Eclipse installation path. You will probably find a zip, but without the extension. Try by deleting it, after doing a backup elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Are you behind a corporate network? Maybe there is some kind of proxy blocking the host connection.